# How to Snap Lines in CartoDB

Tags: carto, maps

I'm trying to create a project that maps out bus routes in CartoDB, and a lot of the streets have a lot of curves and turns. Is there a way to snap the lines to the street grid?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the basemap from CartoDB there is no way you can snap the street lines on the grid. But if you have shapefiles for the streetlines, you can edit them in another software called QGIS (free open software). Then, export that data onto CartoDB.